# Center items within a container

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Lately I'm using Qt Designer to build a user interface,
And I'm trying to center items (horizontally) in their parent container.

[image: MainWindow]

I tried to do it using Grid Layout,
I also tried adding Spacers on both sides of each item,
But it didn't work.

How do you do that?

My .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>200</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut </string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="wordWrap">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: In the latest Qt Designer, right-click a widget in the Object Inspector and choose your preference under Layout Alignment.

Comment: Thanks! It works!

Do you know how to get to this setting in the Property Editor?

Comment: Reset the size policy of those widgets (click on the small red arrow button near the `sizePolicy` property), as setting them to `Fixed` forces them to use their size hint while preventing them to fill the available size of the layout cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest Qt Designer, right-click a widget in the Object Inspector and choose your preference under Layout Alignment.

Comment: That's not in "the latest", but was there at least since Qt4. Besides, the problem was caused by a wrong size policy setting.